# Styling a parent element of a child in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would really appreciate any help you could provide on this matter. I am trying to style the parent of a specific child element.

It seems that this might not be possible in CSS due to technical restraints, but I was wondering if there was a solution available in JavaScript that could achieve this?

I am trying to alter the parent `<a>` element of a `<ul class="children">` child element, only when that `<a>` element has `class="active"`. e.g. there will be other `<a>` elements with `<ul>` child elements which are not active that I don't want to be styled.

If you know of any solution that would be able to achieve this that would be much appreciated! Whilst I am familiar with CSS I am not competent enough in JavaScript to write this myself.

```
<ul class="menu">  
    <li>  
        <a class="active">Active Page</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <a>Something here </a>
        </ul>
    </li>  
    <li>    
        <a>Some Other Page</a>  
        <ul class="children">
            <a>Something here</a>
        </ul>
    </li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: Why are you using `<ul>` elements to hold something other than `<li>` elements?

Comment: Maybe its code for a dropdown menu

Comment: <ul> have children only <li> elements.. you first change <ul class="children"><li><a>Something Here</a></li></ul> and than please clearify your question again. what you wanna output

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you style a.active. (Or haven't I understood the question?)

I.e.

```
a.active {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no css selector to select parent elements. You should also give the parent element a selector you can use to style it.

Also see [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) for more information on the parent selector subject.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really confused by your question but your could give two class names to the same element. Like for the

```
<ul class="children">
```

You could name it to:

```
<ul class="children active">
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you want this:

```
if($('ul.children a').hasClass('active')){
  $('ul.children').sibling('a').addClass('active');
}
```

## see:

I am `trying to alter the parent <a>` element `of a <ul class="children">`

while this is not true, `<a>` is the sibling in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do a style for the class active?

```
.active { 
    background-color: red;
}
```

As per your HTML you could style the exact parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML nested tags are Ok.
No need of javascript
Your css rule should look something like this

```
a.active+ul.children { ...what ever .... }
```

(In order to style the UL class children when its sibling is a class active

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I read it again and again, and now I got it!

```
.menu>li>a.active{
  font-weight:bold
}
```

It will select only the first-level "a.active" children from the first-level "li" children from ".menu" ;)

Hope it helps!